# HAProxy reverse proxying with Docker not working

Tags: haproxy, docker, containers

I have one server. On this server I have one haproxy container, 2x node containers.
I am trying to split up the following.

```
https://mydomain -> 1e node container (x.x.x.x:8080)
https://mydomain:81 -> 2e node container (x.x.x.x:8080)
```

My config:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 notice
    maxconn 2048
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy

defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  10000
    timeout server  10000

listen stats
    bind *:1988 ssl crt /srv/ssl.io.pem
    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats uri /haproxy
    stats auth myuser:mypassword

frontend http-in-beta
    bind *:81 ssl crt /srv/ssl.io.pem
    acl host_mydomain_com_beta      hdr_beg(host) -i mydomain.com
    use_backend mydomain_beta      if host_mydomain_com_beta

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc } # redirect all traffic to https

frontend https-in
    bind *:443 ssl crt /srv/ssl.io.pem
    acl host_mydomain_com          hdr_beg(host) -i mydomain.com
    use_backend mydomain_cluster   if host_mydomain_com

backend mydomain_beta
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    server mydomain_beta 172.17.0.110:8080

backend mydomain_cluster
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    server mydomain_node_s1 172.17.0.109:8080
```

Now the issue I am getting, is that sometimes it works. Sometimes I receive a 503. It's frustrating!

Feels like port 81 and 80 are somehow colliding?

Comment: Ports do not "collide". :)

Comment: @EEAA I just fixed the error, will post in an answer soon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994629/haproxy-random-http-503-errors

Matthew Jones answered my question. I was running not one but TEN HAProxy instances each probably with their own config files.

I have NO idea how this happened, I did update the config around 10 times but always used the command `service haproxy restart`. Weird...

I used the following to acquire the processes and kill them:

```
ps -ef | grep haproxy
kill <PROCESS NUMBER HERE>
service start haproxy
```